# sed got error if no single quotes around the regular expression

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I tried to do the following command in bash:

```
ls -1 | sed s/\(.*\)/"\1"/
```

which is add double quotes around each output of `ls`, but the result shows
`sed: 1: "s/(.*)/\1/": \1 not defined in the RE`

after I add single quotes around the regular expression, I got the right result. the right one is:

`ls -1 | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/'`

theocratically I do not need the outer quotes right? any one has the same experience?

Comment: The quotes aren't there for sed, are there for the shell.

Comment: @franky: or `sed 's/.*/"&"/'`

Comment: @Cyrus what does & mean here?

Comment: From `man sed`: "s/regexp/replacement/": Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that  portion  matched  with replacement.   The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding  matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes are used to disable shell parsing of various sequences including backslash escapes. If you don't use them, your sequences like `\(` are passed to sed as `(`. You may check that by adding `echo` to the beginning of your command.

Answer (score 2):

Sending the command to `echo` will show you what sed sees

```
$ echo sed s/\(.*\)/"\1"/
sed
```

Hmm, the sed script disappeared altogether. The exposed "*" is forcing the shell to try to match files. Let's disable that:

```
$ set -f
$ echo sed s/\(.*\)/"\1"/
sed s/(.*)/\1/
```

The shell ate the quotes and the backslashes. Quoting the sed script:

```
$ echo sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/'
sed s/\(.*\)/"\1"/
```

That gives the right result, sed will see the script you want to give it. How can we do that without quotes

```
$ echo sed s/\\\(.\*\\\)/\"\\1\"/
sed s/\(.*\)/"\1"/
```

And that's ugly.